# About solving a system of first order ODEs with non constant coefficients

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve this system of ODEs 
\begin{align*}
&S'(t)=-\lambda(t)S(t)+{\tau}R(t)\\
&I'(t)=\lambda(t)S(t)-{\gamma}I(t)+r(t)L(t)\\
&R'(t)=(1-q){\gamma}I(t)-{\tau}R(t)\\
&L'(t)=q{\gamma}I(t)-r(t)L(t) \\
\end{align*}
so if I write it in compact form: $X'(t)=A(t)X(t)$. 
Now, my problem is the matrix A, because it also depends on t.
I have read that in order to solve this problem I should use exponential matrix, but in order to solve it I have to prove that the matrix commute with its integral i.e. 
$$
A(t)\int_{0}^{t}A(s)ds = \int_{0}^{t}A(s)ds{A(t)}
$$ 
But unfortunately it does not. 
So is there another procedure that I can try to use to solve this system analitically or is it impossible and I am force to find a numerical one? 
I hope that someone of you can give me some hints-suggestions. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have some more information on $r(t)$ and $\lambda(t)$? Are they arbitrary input/control terms, or do they obey a differential equation themselves? Are they perhaps related to the other model variables? Maybe they're periodic in time?
Secondly: are you sure the last term in the last equation is $- r(t) I(t)$, not $-r(t) L(t)$?

Comment: Yes, you are right! There is a mistake in the last equation.. now I will edit it! About r(t) I don't have informations, and $\lambda(t)$ is related to I(t) as $$\lambda(t)=f(t)\int_{0}^{t}g(s)I(s)ds$$.. where f and g are arbitrary input terms

Comment: Ok, that helps.. any information on $f(t)$ and $g(s)$ though?
And.. maybe in the first equation $-\tau R(t)$ must be $+ \tau R(t)$?

Comment: Yes, you were right again about the sign, sorry. No, I don't know anything apart from that they are scalar functions.. I was thinking to start with the third equation, because it's the only one with constant coefficients, but then I don't know how to proceed.. So I still don't have any idea..

Comment: Hmm.. in general, you can't say much when some parameters are functions of time. Other than the observation that the total $S+I+L+R$ is conserved (which is how I spotted the typos), there isn't much to say analytically, as far as I can see.

Comment: Do you think that with Mathematica is possible to have an analitical expression? I think that to make things more complex I can assume that also r is not time dependent and hence I will have only $lambda$ depending on t.

Comment: Even for one time-dependent parameter $\lambda(t)$: no. Only when the matrix $A$ is not explicitly time dependent, you can say something analytically.